# Calling web services method with php , returns unrecognizable characters

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services

I call a web service  with php , and display the results into post in wordpress , but response returns with unrecognizable characters.I use XYZ PHP Code plugin for this.

Below the code

```
//API Url
$url = 'http://myUrl/s1services';
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
 'service' => 'login',    
 'username' => 'username',
 'password' => 'password',
 'appid' =>  '256'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonData = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

the result  below

> �MQ�N�@��ɬ�tJ�׮v���>B�����`x����q,��C�A$�`�koy��.ι���G�z=�"�C�p\ \o����`8���L�Zd|6`wE��nGP�BǶ-ƜT�*��p?2)ɛ��f��gr1�ľOy��[ಎ'�87pk����P »q9�н�?�,�c�٦�ZU�rI��ŉ�TS�ӳ�b�}] tzh:�UI���ρ9[���D��������P�$���~~_��ߐ(�y�H<��>�?�z���l���9RuH�]�t��y�RS�C��n��WPqu�\2�ê�z���x�Wy BxMHR��R������@K�$IJ���^��s�Z;���o��j�~������ɠ��

Where can the error be found?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The response might be gzipped, research in the direction of curl and gzip…

Comment: I agree, this looks like binary data. Dump the header received to look what mimetype it is and if there is a gzip or other compression.

Comment: piece of code that i have add 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
 
the result now looks like this

{"success":true,"clientID":"9J8pHKvuKqrCQ69N9JL4HNLNLK5JH6mbDKD3Ld9HLKnsL75CILLaLsLqSqLbUMPGKbLKNrfLPLybDqH0KazPPLLNLaL7LK9vHG", "objs":[{"COMPANY" : "1000","COMPANYNAME" : "������� Demo ��","BRANCH" : "1000","BRANCHNAME" : "����� - ����","MODULE" : "13","MODULENAME" : "�������","REFID" : "47","REFIDNAME" : "����������� AE","USERID" : "1"}